# Convert JSON object Array

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object

So I have checkbox that catch value "role". Each role looks like this:

When I check few roles in checkbox list, I push them in array "selectedRoles"
Problem I get is that when I go to console.log and print result console.log(this.selectedRoles); ,

I get `(2) ["[object Object]", "[object Object]"]` or more (depends on how much roles I select). I am unable to roll them out so I can see properties of every role cause I want them to do PUT with service. I'm using Angular 2.

html:

```
<div class="roles-div">
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <label class="label-roles">Select User Roles</label>
</div>
<form #rolesForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitRole(rolesForm)" >
<div class="flex-column-center">
    <div class="flex-center width90 height300 checkbox-div">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let role of context.roles">
                    <input class="roles-li" type="checkbox" [checked]="userRolesNames.indexOf(role.name)>-1"  name="role" value="{{role}}" (change)="selectRole(option, $event)">{{ role.label }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column-center2 width35">
        <button class="btn-main10" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div> 
</form>
```

ts:

```
export class AddRolePopupComponent extends PopupAbstract<any> implements OnInit {

userRoles = [];
userRolesNames = [];
selectedRoles = [];


constructor( private userService: UserService, private companyService: CompanyService, public dialog: DialogRef<any> ) {

    super( dialog, dialog.context );
}

ngOnInit() {        
    this.userService.getRolesForUser(this.context.id).subscribe(
        response => { this.handleSucess( response ); },
        error => { console.error( error ); },
    );
    }


handleSucess(response) {
        this.userRoles = response;
        this.userRolesNames = response.map(userRole => userRole.name);
}

submitRole(rolesForm){
    console.log(rolesForm.value);
}

selectRole(category, event) {
    var index = this.selectedRoles.indexOf(event.target.value);
    if (event.target.checked) {
        this.selectedRoles.push(event.target.value);
     } else {
        if (index !== -1) {
            this.selectedRoles.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    console.log(this.selectedRoles);
}
```

Comment: we are going to need to see a bit more of your code

Comment: can you show the code where you log the array ?

Comment: Let me know If you need anything else

Comment: If you want to log an object, serialize it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `value` with `ngValue` directive :

```
<input class="roles-li" type="checkbox" [checked]="userRolesNames.indexOf(role.name)>-1"  name="role" [ngValue]="role" (change)="selectRole(option, $event)">
```

**EDIT :**

Since `ngValue` isn't supported in your Angular's version , you can pass `role` directly as a parameter to the method `selectRole` , so you will not use the `event.target.value`:

so in your **Html** :

```
 <input class="roles-li" type="checkbox" [checked]="userRolesNames.indexOf(role.name)>-1"  name="role"  (change)="selectRole(option, $event, role)">
```

and in your **ts** :

```
selectRole(category, event , role) {
    var index = this.selectedRoles.indexOf(role);
    if (event.target.checked) {
        this.selectedRoles.push(role);
     } else {
        if (index !== -1) {
            this.selectedRoles.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    console.log(this.selectedRoles);
}
```

Comment: I get error:
Can't bind to 'ngvalue' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("nput class="roles-li" type="checkbox" [checked]="userRolesNames.indexOf(role.name)>-1"  name="role" [ERROR ->][ngvalue]="role" (change)="selectRole(option, $event)">{{ role.label }}
     </li>
    </ul>

Comment: i edited my answer , try  `[ngValue]` instead of `[ngvalue]`

Comment: can u tell me please which version of angular are you using ?

Comment: "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",

Comment: i think the problem is in you Angular's Version ,try now with `[value]` ,if it doesn't work , what i suggest is to pass the  `role` directly as a parameter to the method `selectRole`

Comment: I tried with [value] ...and I get: (2) ["[object Object]", "[object Object]"]
0
:
"[object Object]"
1
:
"[object Object]"
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)

I might try to pass role directly

Comment: @Muhamed I got bit of confused...You wouldn't mind showing me what to change in code?

Comment: check the answer now

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not binding `value` to a object for a checkbox. Instead I would just pass the `role` with the function in the DOM.

```
(change)="selectRole(role, option, $event)"
```

This ends up being a bit cleaner and easier to understand.